# How can I concatenate one file into a list of files which are inside different directories?

Tags: bash, find, cat

I'm working in bash and I'm trying to put one text file at the end of every file in different directories, I have something like

```
BaseFile
/Dir1/File1
/Dir2/File2
/DirN/FileN
```

I want to put the text of BaseFile at the end of every File1, File2, ..., FileN, overwriting them. I've tried with find, cat and grep, but can't get the result that I want. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to append the contents to those files *or* overwrite their contents?

Comment: Append but saving in the same file, not create a new one

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most elegant, but will append the contents of BaseFile to any file whose name begins with 'File':

<s>find . -type f -name "File*" -exec cat BaseFile >> "{}" \;</s>

edit:

As gniourf_gniourf pointed out I got that quite wrong. Their comment below is what I was aiming for, and failed

```
find . -type f -name "File*" -exec sh -c 'cat BaseFile >> "$0"' "{}" \;
```

Comment: No! This doesn't work! The redirection `>>` isn't going to do what you think! Maybe you mean: `find . -type f -name "File*" -exec sh -c 'cat BaseFile >> "$0"' "{}" \;`. Your command will happily create a file called `{}` that will contain as many copies of file `BaseFile` that there are found files `:)`.

Comment: Remember, the redirections can be written anywhere (only their relative position matters). So your command will have the same effect as, e.g., `find . -type f -name "File*" -exec cat BaseFile \; >> "{}"`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use loop as well:
`for x in /Dir*/FILE* ; do cat BaseFile >> "$x" ; done`